# OS X Dock Icon update, memory leak with ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-leaks

My OS X application is very often takes a PNG image and displays it as an icon in the dock. The picture may be quite large.

The problem is that each icon update memory usage increases and does not release somewhere old memory. ARC is used.

Update procedure

```
NSImage *icon = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @ "/path/test.png"];
[NSApp setApplicationIconImage: icon];
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can resize the image based on the dock icon size and apply to the applicationIconImage.

Comment: Show your full code, are you doing something else with `icon` reference?

Comment: Right, make sure `icon` isn't used elsewhere, and potentially use `@autoreleasepool{}` around where you think the old `applicationIconImage` will have its retain count go to zero.